# NATS Warning: Internal subscription on "$JS.API.CONSUMER.INFO.stream_name.consumer_name" took too long: 2.265209187s

Tags: c#, .net-core, nats.io, nats-streaming-server

I have up to 10 subscribers who connect to the NATS server and continuously fetch the messages.The basic code which I use to subscribe the messages is:

```
IJetStreamPullSubscription sub = js.PullSubscribe(subject, pullOptions);
```

Some subscriber use this:

```
IList<Msg> list = sub.Fetch(100, 1000);
```

Some subscriber use this:

```
sub?.PullNoWait(100);
m = sub.NextMessage(1000);
```

The NATS server logs are generating warnings like:

```
[WRN] Internal subscription on "$JS.API.CONSUMER.INFO.org_log_stream.durable-Log" took too long: 2.265209187s
[WRN] 172.23.0.1:46074 - cid:494 - "v0.14.5.0:.NET" - Readloop processing time: 2.375663549s
```

I am trying to figure out these warnings. Please help me to understand the possible reasons.